# How do I know if I should continue to support OS 4.3, etc?

Tags: iphone, ios

I've written a few apps now and I've always supported iOS 4.3+
However, now that Apple is up to iOS 6,
I'm wondering if I should continue to support the older iOS?

Is there a way to tell which iOSs my App users are using (count) so I can determine
what to support?

Comment: Without flurry or another analytics service, you cannot get this data.

Comment: Hi Im founder of AskingPoint a free app analytics API, you can use our product to get that kind of information. One of the metrics it provides is versions of iOS your App is running on.

Comment: The way I'm developing, I have left the base SDK at 4.3 until there has been a case to use an iOS 5 or 6 feature. You really need analytics to decide for yourself. Google Analytics can also be used on iOS and provides iOS version in its data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absent already having data about which iOS versions your users are on, your best option is to look at other's data. David Smith's app audiobook's shows 3.9% of users are on iOS 4.3.

http://david-smith.org/iosversionstats/